# How to display 50 digits or more (for example in multiplication) in java?

Tags: java, calculator, digits

I have project that ask me to design a calculator by java and I should put to chioices for the user to choice either display 50 digits or 100 digits.

The problem as you know when I make the multiplication for example or any other operation with big numbers dosen't show all digits, it will display about 20 digits and the left will be as E(some number)!

I tried using `BigDecimal` and `DecimalFormat` but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is the right answer, so you're going to have to try a little harder on that.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class (or the [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class if you're not interested in decimal places.). It should print an arbitrary number of digits just fine. (No need to use `DecimalFormat` btw.)

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("123456789123456789123456789");
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("987654321987654321987654321");

BigDecimal z = x.multiply(y);

System.out.println(z);
```

**Output:**

```
121932631356500531591068431581771069347203169112635269
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BigDecimal

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1.1).multiply(new BigDecimal(1.8)));
```

prints 104 digits

```
1.9800000000000002087219286295294335439472797061332458086428264139311483660321755451150238513946533203125
```

---

Using valueOf converts the `double` as you might expect

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.1).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.8)));
```

prints

```
1.98
```

Comment: Thanks guys it works!, but not for specific number of digits but it free digits, thanks a lot

Comment: You can limit the number of decimal places with `setScale()`